# C# - Counting checkboxes that are selected not working

Tags: c#, .net, checkbox, count, controls

So first I'm getting everything from the database and adding a checkbox for each line of new data, this is all working:

```
while (reader.Read()) {
                    idtema = "";
                    nome = "";
                    filename[i] = "";

                    TableRow rows = new TableRow();
                    TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
                    TableCell cell2 = new TableCell();
                    TableCell cell3 = new TableCell();
                    TableCell cell4 = new TableCell();
                    CheckBox ch = new CheckBox();

                    idtema = reader["IDTema"].ToString();
                    nome = reader["NomeArtista"].ToString();
                    filename[i] = reader["FileNameTrabalho"].ToString();

                    cell1.Text = idtema;
                    cell2.Text = nome;
                    cell3.Text = string.Format("<a href='/Tema" + idtema + "/" + filename[i] + "' data-lightbox='images1'><img height='100%' src = '/Tema" + idtema + "/" + filename[i] + "'>");
                    cell4.Controls.Add(ch);

                    rows.Cells.Add(cell1);
                    rows.Cells.Add(cell2);
                    rows.Cells.Add(cell3);
                    rows.Cells.Add(cell4);

                    TabelaPrincipal.Rows.Add(rows);
                    Button1.Visible = true;
                    i = i + 1;
                }
                con.Close();
```

After this I go to the table and check all the checkboxes (4) and I press the button to read the data:

```
public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int check = 0;

        foreach (Control item in this.TabelaPrincipal.Controls)
        {
            if((item is CheckBox) && ((CheckBox) item).Checked)
            {
                TabelaPrincipal.Visible = false;
                Button1.Visible = false;
                DropArtista.Visible = false;
                DropEscola.Visible = false;
                DropConcelho.Visible = false;

                check += 1;
                Response.Write(check);
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

The if doesn't work and it goes to the 'else' and that's it (not even checking if its selected), how do I change so it reads all my checkboxes and the columns?

Comment: I dont know if I understood your issue, but when you do this condition: if((item is CheckBox) && ((CheckBox) item).Checked) you want to know if the item is a checkbox and if it is checked. So you need to increment your check variable here and not in the else condition. The else condition is counting every item that is not a checkbox or if it a checkbox and it is not checked.

Comment: As Rafael said, if you want to count checked checkboxes, you have to increment inside 'if' block and not the 'else' block

Comment: I edited it now, that's not it, its going to the else and not counting how many checkboxes I have properly. Thanks.

Comment: Your controls are inside the Cells (TabelaPrincipal.Rows.Cells.Controls). Maybe you need to loop into rows and cells to find the controls.
Something like that:
foreach (Cell cell in this.TabelaPrincipal.Rows.Cells)
 foreach (Control item in cell)

Comment: JUST TO EDIT THE COMMENT ABOVE:
Your controls are inside the Cells (TabelaPrincipal.Rows.Cells.Controls). Maybe you need to loop into rows and cells to find the controls.
Something like that:
foreach (Row row in this.TabelaPrincipal.Rows)
    foreach (Cell cell in row.Cells)
 foreach (Control item in cell.Controls)

Comment: It could see that there are 4 cells but it didnt check for controls, so it never goes into the last foreach

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

```
public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)   {
    int check = 0;

    foreach (TableRow row in this.TabelaPrincipal.Rows) {
        foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells) {
            foreach (Control item in cell.Controls) {
                    if((item is CheckBox) && ((CheckBox) item).Checked)
                    {
                        TabelaPrincipal.Visible = false;
                        Button1.Visible = false;
                        DropArtista.Visible = false;
                        DropEscola.Visible = false;
                        DropConcelho.Visible = false;

                        check += 1;
                        //Response.Write(check);
                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }
                }
        }
    }
    Response.Write(check);
}
```

If this was not working, try to do something like this (the both solutions are working here for me):

```
public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     int check = 0;
     foreach (Control control in TabelaPrincipal.Controls)
     {
         check = SearchControl(control, check);
     }

     //Here Check is OK (It has the number of the checkboxes that are checked in the interface)
     Response.Write(check);
}


public int SearchControl(Control control, int check)
    {

        if (control != null && control.Controls !=null && control.Controls.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (Control c in control.Controls)
            {
                check = SearchControl(c, check);
            }                
        }
        else
        {
            if ((control is CheckBox) && ((CheckBox)control).Checked)
            {
                check += 1;
            }
        }



        return check;

    }
```

there are some others solution, but you need to use some JavaScript, JQuery and Ajax. This could change a lot your design (In particular, I don't use asp.net anymore, just HTML with JQuery, JS, Bootstrap and Ajax requests to call the server side methods).

Comment: It could see that there are 4 cells but it didnt check for controls, so it never goes into the last foreach

Comment: Hummm.., something is weird! You have 4 cells, and just the last one have controls. Just In this case it should go into the last foreach (in the others, really dont).

Comment: I'll try to replicate the issue!

Comment: Here is working!!! The first 3 cell of each row doesnt go to the last foreach, but the last one goes and I can verify if the checkbox is checked or not. I didn't modify anything from your code and the mine above!

Comment: Weird, can you show me how you declare your checkbox and if you do anything with it before?

Comment: I just declare like you did. The difference is that I didn't do the interface part. Maybe your issue is when you are recovering the values on Click event. Try to put my code after the con.Close(); (from int check = 0; to the end of foreachs) just to know if it working like here (put a break inside the last foreach).

Comment: Yeah it works that way, maybe there is another way I can do this? Like put a link you can click and it gets the other values instead of a checkbox?

Comment: Can you show us the markup code? I'll try to do the same here, just to undertand better...

Comment: https://pastebin.com/W0K0cXqC , Here it is, I've tried some other things but they are not working as well..

Comment: Here it's working. Now I did exactly the same as you did. I put a break point at the end of the click method (in Response.Write(check);) and when I click on Button1 the value of check is the same of the checkboxes that are checked in the interface.

Comment: I'm tired of this, isn't there any other way? i've tried everything, it can count how many cells there are (4) but it can't find the control.

Comment: can you post your whole code on pastebin or something?

Comment: I put the entier solution here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzMBWh8Au7YTYk5nal9kbEN3bFE/view

I'm simulating your page in the Default.aspx.

Comment: Still not working wtf.. Can you help me find another way? I just want the user to select a drawing and then check which one he chose?

Comment: that is so weird. My shared solution didn't work? Here is everything ok! Try to do the second option (I updated the awnser with a new solution).